# Magento 1.9 Replace Products Images

Tags: product-images, catalog, ce-1.9.1.0

I am trying to **replace images for 1500 products**. So, I replace the images files in Media FTP server and Images not changed in the website !
Why?

**Also after I clear the Flush Catalog Images Cache and nothing changed!**

**Anyone can help?**

Comment: first take the backup of media/catalog/product/cache folder and remove the cache folder then flush magento image cache.